# Is there a way to set different destination order with mysql-router?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-cluster, mysqlrouter

I have innodb cluster setup with 3 mysql instances. Each instance is on different server and each server has mysql-router also.

I would like each mysql-router on each server to try to connect to the mysql instance  on the same server. Is this possible?

Currently all mysql-router will check the "destinations=metadata-cache://mycluster/default?role=PRIMARY" option and try to connect to the top server. Is there a way so each mysql-router trys to first try to connect to different instances? (the instance on the same server as mysql-router)

Answer (score 1):

using different specific host order, rather than using metadata-cache in mysql-router config "destination" option on each mysql-router seems to do it.

ie.
destination=server1,server2,server3